Field requires version 2 of the R Extensions SDK (current min is 0): android.provider.MediaStore#ACTION_PICK_IMAGES , How do I change it?
I tried to pick an image from gallery, but it says:

Field requires version 2 of the R Extensions SDK (current min is 0): android.provider.MediaStore#ACTION_PICK_IMAGES".

How do I change it? Here's the code:
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
resultLauncher.launch(intent);


You can use this code:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    MediaStore.getPickImagesMaxLimit()
} else {
    100
}

In the source code of getPickImagesMaxLimit() function this value is equal 100
